# Grid Chart using GWT

Tags: gwt, grid, charts

Is there any library in gwt that will create grid chart, something similar to this : http://www.eyescience.com/images/vision/amsler_grid.gif.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look at  the following url.I think google visualization api will be useful for your case(try Scatter chart).

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html

http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=gwt-google-apis&s=gwt-google-apis&t=VisualizationSampleApplications

http://code.google.com/p/ofcgwt/

Comment: Hi, when i say grid chart its not for creating pie chart or bar chart. Its something like a background on which you can drop widgets(some like visio , dia etc have, white background with black lines). I thought it was called grid chart. I am sorry if that is wrong. Do you know anything similar to the one i am trying to describe for gwt?
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering restricting yourself to browers that support Canvas, GWT has experimental support for that.

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html

Here's a nifty demo:

http://code.google.com/p/gwtcanvasdemo/